# Index not found- but the index is in the csv sheet as the other column names

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to use pandas to convert some string columns to float (pd.get_dummies). I have four columns have to convert, but python keeps trace back to the KEYERROR saying that one of my index (which is named "CODER" is not found). I have changed the column name to "CDR" and "Coder" but still does not work. Can someone tell me why?

```
data = pd.read_csv('/Users/Weindependent/Desktop/hw.csv')
data1 = pd.get_dummies (data,columns['SCHOOL','Class','CODER','Activity'])
```

Comment: `@WY G`, please try to paste few lines of your `hw.csv`, it seems you are struggling and no one is here to help you. Already most of your posts are already downvoted. Actually, they did wrong by downvoting and without specifying the reason.

Comment: I got your problem, it was just because of a little mistake `@WY G`. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have done only a little mistake i.e. `columns[...]` in place of `columns=[...]`.

Have a look at the below working example (or you can have a look at this [notebook file - py_dummies.ipynb](https://github.com/hygull/trypandas/blob/master/StackOverflow/pd_dummies/pd_dummies.ipynb) on my Github account for better look of data).

> hw.csv

```
SCHOOL,Class,CODER,Activity
Boston School,XI,WY G,Learning Programming
CG School,XII,Malinikesh,Enjoying PHP
Model School,X,Rishikesh,Enjoying Python
Boston School,X,Tiny Ojha,Learning Java
CG School,XII,Pinky Markus,Enjoying PHP
Boston School,XII,WY G,Learning Python
Model School,XI,Rishikesh,Enjoying C
Boston School,XII,WY G,Learning Java
Model School,X,Raghvndra,Enjoying C
```

> pd_dummies.py

```
import pandas as pd 

data = pd.read_csv('hw.csv')

print(data)
#           SCHOOL Class         CODER              Activity
# 0  Boston School    XI          WY G  Learning Programming
# 1      CG School   XII    Malinikesh          Enjoying PHP
# 2   Model School     X     Rishikesh       Enjoying Python
# 3  Boston School     X     Tiny Ojha         Learning Java
# 4      CG School   XII  Pinky Markus          Enjoying PHP
# 5  Boston School   XII          WY G       Learning Python
# 6   Model School    XI     Rishikesh            Enjoying C
# 7  Boston School   XII          WY G         Learning Java
# 8   Model School     X     Raghvndra            Enjoying C

print(pd.get_dummies(data, columns=['SCHOOL']))
#   Class         CODER              Activity  SCHOOL_Boston School  SCHOOL_CG School  SCHOOL_Model School
# 0    XI          WY G  Learning Programming                     1                 0                    0
# 1   XII    Malinikesh          Enjoying PHP                     0                 1                    0
# 2     X     Rishikesh       Enjoying Python                     0                 0                    1
# 3     X     Tiny Ojha         Learning Java                     1                 0                    0
# 4   XII  Pinky Markus          Enjoying PHP                     0                 1                    0
# 5   XII          WY G       Learning Python                     1                 0                    0
# 6    XI     Rishikesh            Enjoying C                     0                 0                    1
# 7   XII          WY G         Learning Java                     1                 0                    0
# 8     X     Raghvndra            Enjoying C                     0                 0                    1

data1 = pd.get_dummies(data, columns=['SCHOOL','Class','CODER','Activity'])
print(data1)
#    SCHOOL_Boston School  SCHOOL_CG School  SCHOOL_Model School  Class_X  Class_XI  Class_XII  CODER_Malinikesh  CODER_Pinky Markus  CODER_Raghvndra  CODER_Rishikesh  CODER_Tiny Ojha  CODER_WY G  Activity_Enjoying C  Activity_Enjoying PHP  Activity_Enjoying Python  Activity_Learning Java  Activity_Learning Programming  Activity_Learning Python
# 0                     1                 0                    0        0         1          0                 0                   0                0                0                0           1                    0                      0                         0                       0                              1                         0
# 1                     0                 1                    0        0         0          1                 1                   0                0                0                0           0                    0                      1                         0                       0                              0                         0
# 2                     0                 0                    1        1         0          0                 0                   0                0                1                0           0                    0                      0                         1                       0                              0                         0
# 3                     1                 0                    0        1         0          0                 0                   0                0                0                1           0                    0                      0                         0                       1                              0                         0
# 4                     0                 1                    0        0         0          1                 0                   1                0                0                0           0                    0                      1                         0                       0                              0                         0
# 5                     1                 0                    0        0         0          1                 0                   0                0                0                0           1                    0                      0                         0                       0                              0                         1
# 6                     0                 0                    1        0         1          0                 0                   0                0                1                0           0                    1                      0                         0                       0                              0                         0
# 7                     1                 0                    0        0         0          1                 0                   0                0                0                0           1                    0                      0                         0                       1                              0                         0
# 8                     0                 0                    1        1         0          0                 0                   0                1                0                0           0                    1                      0                         0                       0                              0                         0
```